# rails 4.2 Where to write the Bullet's whitelist code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and using the Bullet gem to detect n+1 queries. There is a method to write whitelist to ignore the n+1 query warnings on some special associations. But I do not know where should I write this part of code. It seems not right written  in the rails config files.

Comment: what sort of code are you looking to add? What sample method did it give you?

Answer (score 4):

In the `config/environments/development.rb` is where you will write the configuration for the bullet gem.

so to whitelist you need to write the code as below.

```
config.after_initialize do
  Bullet.add_whitelist :type => :n_plus_one_query, :class_name => "Post", :association => :comments
  Bullet.add_whitelist :type => :unused_eager_loading, :class_name => "Post", :association => :comments
  Bullet.add_whitelist :type => :counter_cache, :class_name => "Country", :association => :cities
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI - the documentation has been updated. It is no longer add_whitelist, instead it's add_safelist.

```
config.after_initialize do
  Bullet.add_safelist :type => :n_plus_one_query, :class_name => "Post", :association => :comments
  Bullet.add_safelist :type => :unused_eager_loading, :class_name => "Post", :association => :comments
  Bullet.add_safelist :type => :counter_cache, :class_name => "Country", :association => :cities
end
```